# Cant pass parameter in razor file to OnClick event (cannot convert from 'void' to 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.EventCallback')

Tags: asp.net, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

Need a little help creating custom select component

I am attempting to create a custom form select component.  The component will contain my own custom markup rather than using the  tag as it needs a completely different UI beyond which I can style with css.

The component should be able to bind it's value to a string / int / decimal model property which is where I am having trouble.

This is what I have so far:

MySelect.razor

```
@typeparam TValue
@inherits InputBase<TValue>
@namespace Accounting.Web.Components

@foreach (var option in Options)
{
    <button @onclick="OnClick(option.Value)">@option.Value</button>
}
```

MySelect.razor.cs

```
namespace Accounting.Web.Components
{
    public partial class MySelectOption<TValue>
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public TValue Value { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class MySelect<TValue> : InputBase<TValue>
    {
        [Parameter]
        public string Id { get; set; } = "ESelect";

        [Parameter]
        public List<MySelectOption<TValue>> Options { get; set; }
        protected override bool TryParseValueFromString(string? value, [MaybeNullWhen(false)] out TValue result, [NotNullWhen(false)] out string? validationErrorMessage)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void OnClick(TValue value)
        {
            Value = value;
        }
    }
}
```

And then in Index.razor:

```
<MySelect Options="@options" @bind-Value="AddDto.Description" TValue="string">
```

So when using the component I should be able to bind it to a property of any type (but usually int or string) which I pass as the type param TValue.

However, the line below is causing an issue:

```
<button @onclick="OnClick(option.Value)">@option.Value</button>
```

Argument 2: cannot convert from 'void' to 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.EventCallback'

How can I pass the option.Value (which is always a string) to the onCLick event?  Or alternatively modify the code above so that I can accomplish my initially stated goal?

Comment: Try `@onclick="() => OnClick(option.Value)"`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# Blazor WebAssembly: Argument 2: cannot convert from 'void' to 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.EventCallback'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64962821/c-sharp-blazor-webassembly-argument-2-cannot-convert-from-void-to-microsoft)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have more that one issue, but the important one is trying to update `Value`.  Value is an "input" into the control.  The updated value is passed back to parent by calling `ValueChanged`.  However, calling `ValueChanged` directly bypasses the built in functionality in `InputBase` and it's interaction with the `EditContext`.

This demonstrates the basics of inheriting from `InputBase`.

To leverage the built in functionality, you need to either:

1. Set the value by setting `CurrentValueAsString` from the markup and then providing a custom `TryParseValueFromString` to convert from a string to your type (there's a `BindConverter` helper you can use - it's what `InputNumber` and other input controls use).
2. Set the value directly by setting `CurrentValue`.  This bypasses `TryParseValueFromString`.

Your `MySelect`.

I've prettied up your buttons and abstracted your list to an `IEnumerable`.

```cs
@typeparam TValue
@inherits InputBase<TValue>
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms;
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
@using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;

<div class="btn-group" role="group">
@foreach (var option in Options)
{
    <button class="@btnColour(option.Value)" @onclick="() => OnClick(option.Value)">@option.Value</button>
}
</div>

@code {
    [Parameter] public IEnumerable<MySelectOption<TValue>> Options { get; set; } = new List<MySelectOption<TValue>>();


    private string btnColour(TValue? value)
    {
        if (this.Value is null) 
         return "btn btn-outline-primary";

        return this.Value.Equals(value) 
        ? "btn btn-primary" 
        : "btn btn-outline-primary";

    }

    protected override bool TryParseValueFromString(string? value, [MaybeNullWhen(false)] out TValue result, [NotNullWhen(false)] out string? validationErrorMessage)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void OnClick(TValue? value)
    {
        CurrentValue = value;
    }
}
```

And then here's a demo page to show it in use.

```cs
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

<EditForm Model=@model>
    <MySelect Options="@options" @bind-Value=model.Description TValue="string" />
</EditForm>

<div class="alert alert-info m-3">
    Description: @model.Description 
</div>

@code {
    private Model model = new();

    IEnumerable<MySelectOption<string>> options =
        new List<MySelectOption<string>>() {
        new MySelectOption<string> { Id = 1, Value = "France" },
        new MySelectOption<string> { Id = 1, Value = "Spain" },
        new MySelectOption<string> { Id = 1, Value = "Portugal" },
    };

    public class Model
    {
        public string? Description { get; set; }
    } 
}
```

For reference you can find the source code for all the standard `InputBase` controls here: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/tree/main/src/Components/Web/src/Forms

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  he initial problem is solved therefore I will accept this as the answer.  However, the additional information you shared regarding the use of a BindCoverter Helper seems interesting but I couldn't work out how to use it.  Any code samples you can add would be appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at the code for `InputNumber` here https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Components/Web/src/Forms/InputNumber.cs

Comment: The link was very helpful.  That together with your previous answers has helped me accomplish exactly what I needed.   Blazor also infers the type of the value being passed so I don't need to pass it the TValue param - Blazor is pretty impressive.

Answer (score 0):

With help and suggestions from previous answers, below is the solution I arrived at:

Index.razor

```
<MySelect Options="@options" @bind-Value="AddDto.InvestmentEntityId">
</MySelect>

@AddDto.InvestmentEntityId    // integer property

<MySelect Options="@options" @bind-Value="AddDto.Description">
</MySelect>

@AddDto.Description    // string property
```

MySelect.razor

```
@typeparam TValue
@inherits InputBase<TValue>
@namespace Accounting.Web.Components

@foreach (var option in Options)
{
    <button @onclick="() => OnClick(option.Value)">@option.Value</button>
}
```

MySelect.razor.cs

```
namespace Accounting.Web.Components
{
    public partial class MySelectOption
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class MySelect<TValue> : InputBase<TValue>
    {
        [Parameter]
        public List<MySelectOption> Options { get; set; }

        protected override bool TryParseValueFromString(string? value, [MaybeNullWhen(false)] out TValue result, [NotNullWhen(false)] out string? validationErrorMessage)
        {
            if (BindConverter.TryConvertTo<TValue>(value, null, out result))
            {
                validationErrorMessage = null;
            }
            else
            {
                validationErrorMessage = "Err : Select value";
            }
        }

        public void OnClick(string value)
        {
            TValue tmpValue;
            BindConverter.TryConvertTo<TValue>(value, null, out tmpValue);
            CurrentValue = tmpValue;
        }
    }
}
```

It's probably not perfect but I hope it helps anyone looking to do the same.